# creating dictionary using pandas.dataframe from csv

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
#from pandas import DataFrame 

import datetime
import pandas.io.data
from pandas_datareader import data, wb

df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')
grouped = df.groupby(['Arrival','Date', 'Time'])
for name, group in grouped:
    print (name)
    print(group)
```

```
AuthorID    Arrival     Departure    Date            Time
1922        Paris       New York    09/12/10    10:00:00 AM
1002        Los Angeles California  02/12/09    09:00:00 AM
1901        Paris       Nigeria     02/09/09    10:00:00 AM
1922        Paris       New York    02/09/09    10:00:00 AM
1002        Paris       California  09/12/10    10:00:00 AM
1099        Paris       China       02/09/09    10:00:00 AM
1901        Los Angeles Paris       02/12/09    09:00:00 AM
```

I want to create a dictionary using Arrival and departure, then find author ID than have the same arrival or departure on particular dates and time.

Comment: probably just as easy create the dict directly from your csv

Comment: Please can show me how? I don't know how to go about creating a dictionary from csv file. If you can see, under "Arrival" i have some author who appear to be in PARIS on the same day, the same time. In this case, I want to make the PARIS dictionary then use date as key.